Live updates notification or widget on locked screen in android
In android i want to show live updated like zomato order shows on widget even if the app is killed, how can i achieve this?
I search foreground service that wont help here nor work manager. i want that system should not stop that service and i should get constant updates.

Zomato presumably uses Firebase Cloud Messaging to deliver messages to the device regarding order status.

ok thanks, what i do at app side to accept notification from fcm even though app is killed state and how to show widget on locked screen

So long as the user does not force-stop your app (e.g., via Settings), FCM will deliver messages to your app. App widgets have not been supported on the lockscreen in several years.
